# Java 6: Copy and manipulate files

Tags: java, io, bufferedreader, filewriter

### What I want to do...

I have XML-Files with names like *SomeName999999blablabla.xml* with lots of content, where almost every line contains the string `"999999"`. I need identical xml-files where `999999` is replaced by `888888`, `777777`, and so on, in the name and the file's content.

### The problem...

My code works fine and actually creates all the files I need, BUT there are sometimes tiny errors. Like in one line an E is "randomly" replaced by a D (it seems to be always one letter lower than what its supposed to be, but I can't confirm that 100%). Its not a lot, like one or two instances in 60 files, each file being about 100MB. But since its an xml this is a real problem, as this often is a schema violation, which causes a crash in later processing.
I have absolutely no idea where this is coming from or how to fix it, please help.

### My code so far...

```
private void createMandant(String mandant) throws Exception {
    String line;
    File dir = new File(TestConstants.getXmlDirectory());

    for (File file : dir.listFiles()) {
        if (file.getName().endsWith((".xml")) && file.getName().contains("999999")) {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsolutePath().replace("999999", mandant));

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                fw.write(line.replace("999999", mandant) + "\r\n");
            }

            br.close();
            fw.close();
        }
    }
}
```

### Environment...

We are on Java 6. As mentioned before the files are quite large. Like 100MB, several hundred thousand lines each.

Comment: Try another machine, could be a hardware problem.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be a problem with String.replace()
I have replaced it with StringBuilder:

```
  while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                index = 0;
                // fw.write(line.replace("999999", mandant) + "\r\n");
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(line);
                index = builder.indexOf("999999");
                if (index > 0) {
                    fw.write(builder.replace(index, index + 6, mandant).toString() + "\r\n");
                } else {
                    fw.write(line + "\r\n");
                }
            }
```

... and now it seems to work. Two runs have already completed without any problems.

But that seems very strange. Could it really be that a heavily used function like String.replace() just randomly gets single letters wrong every few million method calls?

Comment: You for sure have a hardware issue, do a ram test and check your disks.

Comment: Why does StringBuilder not have problems with this?

Comment: StringBuilder does copy memory during replace, while string.replace uses a regex which copies char by char. I'd guess more operations here are just increasing the probability of a bit flipping due to your hardware issues.